# Why would image paths in wordpress suddenly change?

Tags: images, urls, media-library

I'm using the Everglades WP theme, and have had no issues until suddenly I found all the images have different paths in the browser.

Where they are: http://localhost:8888/dev.brickandpixeldesign/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image.jpg

Instead they look like this: http://i2.wp.com/localhost/dev.brickandpixeldesign/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image.jpg

I'm not sure where the i2.wp.com (sometimes shows up as i0.wp.com) is coming from, or why the path would change in the first place. I've tried disabling plugins, and re-saving permalinks, but to no avail. All the images show up with the correct paths in the Media folder, but not online. I can't for the life of me figure out what might have happened, and have never seen this before.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you use the Jetpack Plugin with Photon function (Wordpress.com photo CDN)

https://jetpack.me/support/photon/
https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/photon/

You have to deactivate the Photon option in the Jetpack plugin settings.

Comment: Still the right answer, except nowadays it's under the Performance tab and called "Enable site accelerator"